# ATTiny32xx, capacitor on RESET/UPDI pin

Tags: capacitor, attiny, reset

I am working on a project using an ATTiny3227. [(Datasheet for reference)](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATtiny3224-3226-3227-Data-Sheet-DS40002345A.pdf)

All ATTinys of this series share one pin for UPDI (programming) and RESET.
In the datasheet it is recommended to add a capacitor from RESET to Ground (see the following image from the datasheet)
[image: From the datasheet]

Doesn't a capacitor on the UPDI/RESET line interfere with the data transfer during programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct- you must not  have a capacitor on that pin if UPDI is to be used. [Source](https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/AVR---Hardware-Design-Considerations-for-UPDI-pin), emphasis added:

> **Question** What are the hardware considerations to be taken care while
> using UPDI interface for programming/debugging?
>
> **Answer** When using the UPDI pin for programming/debugging, the
> following points need to be taken into consideration.
>
> In certain AVR devices, the UPDI and RESET pin are the same pin.
> Generally, it is recommended to connect an external decoupling
> capacitor on the RESET pin. **However, when the same pin is used as UPDI
> for programming and debugging, it is not recommended to connect the
> decoupling capacitor as it will affect the UPDI timing. Hence, If the
> UPDI pin is to be used as a RESET pin, any stabilizing capacitor must
> be disconnected when using UPDI.**
>
> Pull-up resistors on the UPDI line must not be smaller (stronger) than
> 10kΩ. A pull-down resistor should not be used, or it should be removed
> when using UPDI. The UPDI physical is push-pull capable, so only a
> weak pull-up resistor is required to prevent false start bit
> triggering when the line is idle.
>
> If the UPDI pin is used as RESET or GPIO pin, all external drivers on
> the line must be disconnected during programming or debugging since
> they may interfere with the correct operation of the interface.

Comment: Could add a jumper or solder bridge between the cap and ground, and remove it to program/debug.  Reinstall for "normal" operation.

Comment: @rdtsc Or use a 3.5mm  [jack with a tip switch](https://i.imgur.com/zMBktRY.png) if a non-standard cable is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

A capacitor in that configuration acts as a low-pass filter, removing high-frequency noise. The programmer doesn't switch the reset line that quickly, so it isn't interfering with the programmer toggling the reset line.